# How to disable "effectively" windows 10 access to camera?

Tags: windows, windows-10, camera, device-manager

The "device manager" solution, either "disable" or "uninstall" (or both), won't work.
It works until (I believe) you restart the machine.
In this moment the plug and play service will install again and enable.

I know this, because, I have done both of them and next day is installed and enabled without me giving explicit (in the moment) authorization.

Is there anyway?
Is there anyway without disabling plug and play system?

Comment: Disabling camera in device manager works for me even if restart or cold start. Not sure what your real issue is. W10 uses a generic video driver, its called "usbvideo.sys" it can be found in Windows>System32>Drivers, if you can disable the device and then change the name of the driver file usbvideo.sys by adding a number at the end usbvideo2.sys, then reboot, it should disable the driver from loading. Easiest solution is to put tape over the camera lens.

Comment: Hi, I have tested several times. I will try again, but there was never explicit asking to enable again, there it is , enabled and installed.
Actually the tape solution is kind unnecessary, is not much of camera enabled, but some programs by default some times, use the camera.
So it would be nice (due the lack of control on each program, or just -one point control- to have this disable property.

Comment: There is no good way to do what you want if something is enabling the camera against your will.

Comment: The most reliable solution? Unplug it...

Comment: I believe it is not "against my will" because, the plug and play service is working as expected and I gave my approval to this service.

However, maybe there is some configuration in this service to black listed some devices or at least, ask explicitly.
Thanks

Comment: @Attie, it is a laptop.

Comment: Piece of masking tape?

Comment: Check laptop firmware (UEFI, formerly BIOS) options for camera enable/disable, though these probably exist/are only easily found on business-class laptops now.

Comment: Laptops have screws... Depending on how badly you want to disable the webcam, a software solution may not be suitable...

Comment: Please check the solution I accepted. (Y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 10 Has privacy settings:
Windows itself can use it for things like **Windows Hello**.

[image: privacy settings]

Comment: "Denying access blocks Windows […] from accessing the camera". Windows blocks itself. So if the question was "how to make sure my butler doesn't steal from me?", this answer would be like "you can ask your butler not to steal from you". Obviously not the answer for people who don't fully trust their butlers. :)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski then its time to use tape, cardboard, or etc.

Comment: I know, but is this legal to do this to my butler? ;D

Comment: Nice, didn't know about this feature.
I will keep you updated, if tomorrow, it is disable and can not access from app (hangouts, skype, etc) I will mark your answer as correct.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that *may* work.  I have done this in Windows 7, but not in Windows 10.  There is no reason not to try it.

In the device manager, select the camera and go to its properties.  Manually update the driver and select an ***incorrect*** device.  Obviously the device will not work without the proper driver.  Windows (v7 at least) will keep the manually selected device driver until manually changed.